# Swipe and Move Animation Only Run Once when called

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiswipegesturerecognizer

How's it going? I have an IBOutlet of UIImageView with an IBAction swipe gesture function, but I can only swipe the object once. Essentially, there's a 5x5 Game board along with 2 stone-like objects that I can continuously swipe around the board. Swipe once, the stone-like object moves till it reaches the board boundary.
Here's some of the code (for swiping down on stone _one)

```
- (IBAction)swipeDown:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
     NSLog(@"Swipe Right");
     // Get the view I'm interacting with, in this case, _one
     UIView *view = recognizer.view;
     if (view == _one) {
         NSLog(@"Got it 2");
         [self moveOne:CGPointMake(-1, 0) withView:view];
     } else if (view == _two) {
         NSLog(@"Got it 2.5");
         [self moveTwo:CGPointMake(-1, 0) withView:view];
     }
}

- (void)moveOne:(CGPoint)direction withView:(UIView*)stoneView {
     NSLog(@"Got it 5");
     // Bunch of code for getting new position
     // .
     // .
     // .
     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.35f
                           delay:0.0f
                         options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                      animations:^{
                          CGRect rect = stoneView.frame;
                          rect.origin.x = _currentCol*61.5;
                          rect.origin.y = _currentRow*61.5;
                          stoneView.frame = rect;
                      }
                      completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                          NSLog(@"Done finally");
                      }];
}
```

Ok so when I run this, and check out the output, my program makes it to "Done finally" in the Log. But I can only swipe the stones once. Imagine 2048 except you only get to swipe the number '2' tile once and then never interact with the game again.
The gesture recognizer instances for each stone are created in viewDidLoad{} in ViewController.m, same as the swipe and move methods. Why can't I swipe multiple times? Should there be some update in the 'completion:' block of the animate method?

-Thanks let me know if you need more info

Comment: https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwipeView try this..may be helpful for you.

Comment: Not entirely...can't really pick apart the things I would need.  But do you understand what I am asking in terms of getting these methods to be called as many times as I'd like?  Is there a method I need to write or a pre-written method I can incorporate that would let this happen?

Comment: For those that actually come across this, my views weren't being updated in the view hierarchy; they were falling behind the touch interface.  So I just added them to my _board view as subviews after each move (inside the animations: block after the stoneView.frame = rect update).

Comment: So basically you have an ImageView and 2 subVIews right?